# How to combine 2 variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make this work and yes I need it to be built like this,
since I will be changing the variable `%One%`.

```
set One=Help
set HelpPage10=10
set /a %one%Page10=%%one%Page10%-5
echo %HelpPage10%
```

The variable `%HelpPage10%` should be 5, but it is still 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of quick examples:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "One=Help"
Set "HelpPage10=10"
Set /A %One%Page10=%One%Page10-5
Echo %HelpPage10%
Pause
```

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "One=Help"
Set "HelpPage10=10"
Set /A %One%Page10 -=5
Echo %HelpPage10%
Pause
```

*Type `Set /?` at the Command Prompt for the `Set` command's usage information.*

Comment: thank you, ill upvote your answer when i reach 15 reputation

Comment: @Y4hL, you don't upvote it, you select the large check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as the accepted solution.